# ERROR: error pulling image configuration: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character 'F' looking for beginning of value: "Forbidden!"

Tags: linux, docker, whatsapp, docker-compose

I've installed docker 20.10.6 and 1.21.0 on centos linux 7 OS machine and when I run below command I get error

```
docker-compose -f multiconnect-compose.yml up -d
```

**Error**

```
    Creating network "prod_default" with the default driver
Pulling waweb (docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.33.4)...
v2.33.4: Pulling from web
5d3b2c2d21bb: Pulling fs layer
3fc2062ea667: Pulling fs layer
75adf526d75b: Pulling fs layer
83b1bcf5f7c2: Waiting
52b2ced8e9f5: Waiting
6c5be97e59f3: Waiting
bcc722031b67: Waiting
39e5291c3f7a: Waiting
9173dcbad33a: Waiting
a05d1d198795: Waiting
821a900ced2b: Waiting
7616e062595d: Waiting
1ac1f78dc01d: Waiting
3a8b47c3081b: Waiting
e74bc18a6a58: Waiting
65a44e8d2760: Waiting
b14b2ce40262: Waiting
f95b4c881786: Waiting
ERROR: error pulling image configuration: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character 'F' looking for beginning of value: "Forbidden!"
```

I can't find the problem and I'm stuck now. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker registry `docker.whatsapp.biz` is (or rather was) backed by JFrog Bintray. [Bintray however is shutting down](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) and is no longer accessible for non-paying customers since May 1st.

You'll have to contact WhatsApp or Facebook about this.

Comment: We are not a non-paying customer and it was working fine a day ago

Comment: I very much doubt you are the owner of the `docker.whatsapp.biz` registry. So again: Contact WhatsApp/Facebook.